# Use special character in Wordpress permalink or mod_rewrite? How to add "strange" url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I am realy confused. I moved site for my client. This site had event registration form and all users received link to edit their info. Older CMS not used friendy URL and this permalink looks like this

```
 ?pl_aktualizacja-danych,160,p,371,c2dbc3915b9438920981bdb1aad19668
```

where three last variables is client unique numbers.

I need to add this permalink to Wordpress or maybe use mod_rewrite. I don't know. As you know Wordpress cleaning special characters from url

so, how to build page with this url:

```
 ?pl_aktualizacja-danych,160
```

Do you have any idea?

EDIT / UPDATE

Step by step explanation:
My client has separation php script with all the forms. The scripts is not affiliated with WordPress. It is neither a plugin or module but only php code. Link to edit the data is generated by the form and send to users by e-mail. Currently in database we have the 1000 users and all of them have received e-mail with this link. Previous CMS script was called on ?pl_aktualizacja-danych,160 page. Now i need create Wordpress page with same permalinks. Or I need to do mod_rewrite (I guess).

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? you want to generate a link to a user profile? are there things on the user profile that depend of url variables? is the profile page working at this point as it should and you have trouble only with the link in the e-mail?

Comment: I only want page with link like i said. All of 1000 clients have this link, so I can't change permalinks (but maybe I can do .htaccess rewrite?) but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ... you need to 301 redirect to the new page.

Make sure the 301 directive is above the wordpress code in your htaccess file.

Furhter details on htaccess here: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html